# Override asp.net/IIS error page

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, iis-7.5

How to override IIS/asp.net error page like the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/aux ? Without IIS & asp.net version and error details?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a custom page for any error use something like this in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                      defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

        ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To show custom error page that is error specific use something like:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

and yes, more info can be found here as the commenter above posted: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs